# How to find multiple <br> in sequence via document.querySelector?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

If I have a sequence of multiple `<br>`s, how do I display how many sequences do I have?

In other words, I'm trying to count how many times we had `<br><br>` as in two 
s in a row.

```js
// Undesired output:
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('br').length) // 8
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('br+br').length) // 7
```

```html
<div id="test">
Paragraph 1
<br>
<br>
Paragraph 2
<br>Paragraph 2 continued
<br>
<br>
Paragraph 3
<br>Paragraph 3 continued
<br>
<br>
Paragraph 4
</div>
```

Desired output:

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('?????').length) // 3
```

Comment: It's unclear wha you are trying to count, I only ever see 2 successive br elements without text separating them.

Comment: Trying to count how many times we had `<br><br>` as in two <br>s in a row.

Comment: My comment is not going to help you, but I really wondering why do you wanna know this?

Comment: Just trying to locate if this `div` has more than 3 such sequences for analyzing how long my text is.

Comment: Shouldn't you just use a new `<p></p>` for each paragraph instead of adding `<br><br>`

Comment: True, but it's another person's website which I can't modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use regex to find `<br><br>`s:

```js
var p = /<br>[\r\n]*<br>/g;
console.log([...document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML.matchAll(p)].length); // => 3
```

```html
<div id="test">
Paragraph 1
<br>
<br>
Paragraph 2
<br>Paragraph 2 continued
<br>
<br>
Paragraph 3
<br>Paragraph 3 continued
<br>
<br>
Paragraph 4
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('br, div');
console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div id="test">
Paragraph 1
<br>
<br>
Paragraph 2
<br>Paragraph 2 continued
<br>
<br>
Paragraph 3
<br>Paragraph 3 continued
<br>
<br>
Paragraph 4
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a better way to do it, hopefully this helps!

```js
const brTags = document.querySelectorAll('br')
let tagCount = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < brTags.length; i++){
  const string = brTags[i].nextSibling.textContent
      .replaceAll("\n", "")
      .trim();
  if(string.indexOf("Paragraph") > -1 && string.length === 11){tagCount++}
}

console.log ("Tag count: ", tagCount);
```

```html
<div id="test">
Paragraph 1
<br>
<br>
Paragraph 2
<br>Paragraph 2 continued
<br>
<br>
Paragraph 3
<br>Paragraph 3 continued
<br>
<br>
Paragraph 4
</div>
```